# Which code is better programming style

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I have several different objects, but I have to do similar actions with them.
What is better to use:
1. Several methods and use these objects as type parameters. 
2. Use one method which gets System.Object as parameter. And inside this method I will check type of parameter and do some action.

For example I should send notifications for some actions. I have objects Action1, Action2, Action3...ActionN, which contain details of these actions. Should I use:

```
   public void SendNotificationForAction1(Action1 action) {}
   public void SendNotificationForAction2(Action2 action) {}
   public void SendNotificationForActionN(ActionN action) {}
```

or

```
   public void SendNotification(Object action) 
   {
       //here I will check type of action and do something
   }
```

Comment: definitely the first ... but nothing stops you from combining them

Comment: @scibuff, How ? I think compile time binding will be done in first approach

Comment: If the agruments are all different types, why not just overload the same method?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice the 1, 2, ... N, yes, you should overload the methods

Comment: The question is too general.  I'd suggest you rephrase the question title to be more specific to this problem.

Answer (score 8):

The first one is type-safe, the second one is not.  Therefore, if I 've to choose between those two options, I'd chose the first one.

On the other hand, isn't it possible to go with an entirely different approach ?
Where you have one base-class or interface Action, where other classes derive from ?
The interface or base-class could have a '`GetDetailsForNotification`' method, which you implement in the implementors, and you can use that method in the `SendNotificationForAction` method.

something like this, but, offcourse, I do not know if this is viable in your context:

```
interface IAction
{
   string GetDetailsForNotification();
}

public class Action : IAction{
   public string GetDetailsForNotification()
   {
        return "details from Action";
   }
}

public class Action2 : IAction{
   public string GetDetailsForNotification()
   {
        return "details from Action2";
   }
}


public void SendNotificationForAction(IAction action) {

   var details = action.GetDetailsForNotification();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Only suggestion is change the parameter of SendNotificationForAction1 to IAction, rather than Action, to make it a little more generic.

Answer (score 8):

I guess it depends:

Is the code to send notifications more or less the same? Then I would opt for:

```
public void SendNotificationFor<T>(T action) {}
```

otherwise I'd probably choose to [overload](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/) the method:

```
public void SendNotification(Action1 action) {}
public void SendNotification(Action2 action) {}
public void SendNotification(ActionN action) {}
```

Comment: Maybe it was not the best example. Code to send notifications is different and depends on type of Action. So it will be better to overload the method in my case.

Comment: @Tannheuser What would be harder in that case is to make a generic method. It sounds like method overload would be a perfect match! Overloaded methods don't need to share anything other than the name.

Answer (score 2):

The [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) may fit here too:

```
private interface INotificationStrategy<T> // or non-generic with object
{
    void SendNotification(T action);
}

public class StringNotificationStrategy : INotificationStrategy<string>
{
    public void SendNotification(string action)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

A Factory could provide you the correct implementation, and you could provide further implementations without breaking existing interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first approach.

It entails creating more methods, and possibly a bit more code, but I believe it to be much easier to use and typesafe.

Your second approach doesn't allow me to know in compile time what kind of Object the method is expecting without reading the code (imagine you distribute this code to be used as a library), and if I pass the wrong method, the only thing you can do is to make it fail in runtime - not great.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep the method as generic as possible.

The `SendNotification` method could be built like this:

```
public void SendNotification<T>(T action) where T : SpecialAction {
}
```

The class/interface `SpecialAction` can then have methods that are different between the actions. For instance:

```
[abstract class] [interface] SpecialAction {
    public string GetName();
    public bool CanDoX();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As guys said, it depends, but generally I prefer variation(below) of 2nd approach, cause of it's easier to extend in future(of course, if you need).

```
interface ISendNotificationHandler
{
    Type ActionType { get; }
    void SendNotification(object action)
}  


class Action1SendNotificationHandler : ISendNotificationHandler
{
    public Type ActionType {get{return typeof(Action1);}}
    public void SendNotification(object action)
    {
        Action1 a = (Action1)action;
        // TODO: send notification
    }   
}

// your method originally posted 
public void SendNotification(Object action)     
{
        var handlers = new ISendNotificationHandler[]{ new Action1SendNotificationHandler(), /* etc*/}

        // 
        var handler = handlers.FirstOrDefault(h=>action.GetType().IsSubclassOf(h.ActionType))
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler.SendNotification(action);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Handler not found for action " + action);
        }
}
```

Comment: Aleksey, that's why I had asked this question. It's possible that it will have to be extended in future. And I think that 2-nd samle is better in this case.

Comment: `It's possible that it will have to be extended in future` - then I vote for 2-nd as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Observer Pattern

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)  is here.

To keep it short, lets say you have subscribed to a news paper, when ever there is a new edition(event) of news paper, the subscriber will get notified and the new version is delivered.

Answer (score 0):

here is my try :

Every ActionN class is derived from base Action :

```
class Action1: Action, INotify
{
   public void override SendNotification() {...}
}
```

If some notifications have common implementation then have it in Action class.

Now in the class who sends notification do this :

```
class Sender
{
    public void SendNotif(INotify actn)
    {
       actn.SendNotification();
    }

}
```

And send proper object to SendNotif() method.